# How to auto increment a class variable on django model instance creation?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I am trying to auto increment a model (class variable ) by using django signals. It is working fine but only each time I do switch off my computer the count restart to zero. I do not know what I am doing wrong exactly.
Here is the `models.py`

```
class Project(models.Model):
Count = 0

manager = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    related_name="project_managing",
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)


 class Saga(models.Model):
    status = (
        ("Do", "Done"),
        ("Td", "To do"),
        ("Ir", "In Review"),
        ("Un", "Under Review"),
        ("Ap", "Approved"),
        ("Ca", "Cancelled"),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    epic_project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sagas", blank=True, null=True
    )
    epic_status = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True, choices=status)

    epic_key = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is the `signals.py`

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Saga)
def epicKey(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.epic_key:
        instance.epic_key = (
            instance.epic_project.key + "-" + str(instance.epic_project.Count + 1)
        )
        instance.epic_project.__class__.Count += 1
```

Don't really know why it is re-initializing the count variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to do it.

Each Django process keeps it's own memory and all of it will be gone every time that process exits or you shut down the machine because  RAM is volatile.

You need some sort of database like Redis or PostgreSQL for non volatile storage.

I suggest Redis because it's the most simple but you need to make sure it actually saves the data on disk, because by default it only keeps it in RAM.

Comment: If i do understand the default sqlLite3 database is the issue. Can you please explain why it is saved in to the RAM and not in to the database because I will use the MySql database.

Comment: Do you want the Count variable to belong to the object, or the class?

Comment: To the class it self

Comment: You either need to create another table where you store these variables. Or if you only need the number of rows in that table you can just do `Project.objects.all().count()`

Comment: I wanted the first option but since this is only to keep track of a number of instance of another model I had no idea how to implement it since I won't create a instance of that model. And for the second one, once one element is deleted you loose track of the number of items since it is only counting the number of rows.